# How can I get the current time as an LDAP timestamp in Unix?

Tags: date, ldap, active-directory

I want to be able to generate an [ActiveDirectory LDAP timestamp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/convert-datetime-attributes-to-standard-format) in Unix for some tests I need to run. Active Directory stores date/time values as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since the 0 hour on January 1, 1601 until the date/time that is being stored.

How can I do I get the current time in this format?

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal:

```
echo $((($(date +%s) + 11644473600) * 10000000))
```

Detailed explanation:

- `date +%s` gets the current time in seconds since 1970.
- 11644473600 seconds elapsed from 1601 to 1970.
- 10000000 is the conversion from seconds to 100-nanoseconds.